# WinMaximumize for linux

Tags: linux, window-manager

[This rather uncreatively named Windows tool](https://dottech.org/103687/windows-review-winmaximumize/) introduces a keyboard shortcut, upon using which the active window grows to fill all the space available to it (not filled by other windows). This lets you easily tile windows when you need to without going for a full-fledged tiling window manager.

is there a version of that for linux? I am currently using elementaryOS with it's custom desktop environment, but I'd be happy to find an option for *any* linux desktop, GNOME/KDE/Cinnamon/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hilarious since this **WinMaximumize** is something done in spirit of something available on Linux named **Maximumize**...  On the download page he links to a screen recording of how it works on Linux....

But... It is a setting (named **Maximumize**) available in the *compiz-fusion-plugins-extra* package available for the **CompizConfig Settings Manager** available natively in Ubuntu (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194489) for some more details). So it is not officially meant for Elementary OS.

But see this answer on how to [**Install Compiz on Elementary OS**](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/14497)